# Using data class to pass parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is it a good practice in Kotlin to pass many parameters by using data class object?
For example we have function with many parameters:

```
fun find(queryParams: QueryParam) {...}
```

Data class to hold parameters set:

```
data class QueryParams (
   val filter: String? = null,
   val group:  String? = null,
   val sort:   String? = null,
   ...)
```

And if we calling function in a such way:

```
find(QueryParams( filter = vFilter,
                  group  = vGroup,
                  sort   = vSort,
                  .... 
                ))
```

Comment: This is just my opinion, but I would not use it just because some function has multiple params. But there are cases where such pattern is very helpful, e.g. if we need to pass these params to other functions. Or if some params are overloaded, so we can use multiple types when providing the param.

Comment: Since Kotlin allows default parameter values, I think introducing an intermediate class is just extra noise. But an exception would be if the same set of parameters can get passed along to multiple different functions.

Comment: I think you'd need to judge this on a case-by-case basis.  In Kotlin you can name the parameters in a function call (as you do in your constructor call); and you can specify default values so that the caller doesn't need to provide every value.  Those features can greatly reduce the effort and risks involved with having many parameters — though it'll still get unwieldy eventually…

Comment: …But storing the params in an object might make sense if they _belong_ together in some way.  And it could be useful if you want to pass them around more widely (e.g. if you override the function, or have multiple functions with the same params), or log them easily, or memoise (cache) the result, or reduce the impact of future changes, or anything else that treats those params collectively.

Comment: @diggs thanks for the answer, yes i have multiple functions with the same params, and one function can call another with the same set of params, so it allows me to pass QueryParams object to inner function instead of set of params

Answer (score 0):

Making such a class is good if it is reused in many functions, and changing this class (for example, adding a new property to it) will be meaningful for all the functions taking it. Also, it's excellent if this class has some behavior or additional properties that are useful for all the functions. Otherwise, it just complicates the code.